# Visual Basic functions not being resolved

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Cannot figure out when or why... but VB functions (mostly located on Microsoft.VisualBasic dll AFAIK) are not working and now I have lots of compile time errors. ALL the functions are not being resolved, then I have errors like: 'Val' is not declared. 'IsDBNull' is not declared. 'IIF' is not declared. The same occurs with Split, Trim, Int, Chr, etc.

I have lots of 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute' not defined. It happens for all the types under Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace. I'm using visual studio 2010.

I tried to add manually a reference to the DLL, but when adding it I have a 'This component is already automatically referenced by the build system'.

This is pretty annoying... This is a legacy app I have to make some changes on, and I don't know why this is happening. Google did not helped in this case and I have spent several hours trying to workaround this already. The most ugly issue is that this solution used to compile before, I have already implemented some changes on the code already, and now it cannot be used anymore :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [Troubleshooting Broken References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayds71se(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, yes I went all through the doc. already with no luck

Comment: I assume you've tried "Build"->"Clean solution". If you create a new VB project of the same type in VS, does it work with the aforementioned functions? If not, repair VS. If it does, you could add in the files from the currently not-working project, which could be tedious. (I can't remember what the options are in VS2010 for using a version control system, but you might want to investigate that for future use.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton it happens in new projects too. After running a 'repair', I'm not able anymore to run VS2010. I have a message with something like 'only one of your products has SP1 installed', I'm pretty sure the box is up to day with all the updates. I'm pretty pissed off with MS right now...

Comment: It sounds like your _repair_ restored original VS2010 files over an installation with VS2010 SP1 applied.  Since you have nothing to lose other than time, you could try to reapply VS2010 SP1.  If you need a copy, it can be downloaded from [http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/B/A/EBA0A152-F426-47E6-9E3F-EFB686E3CA20/VS2010SP1dvd1.iso](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/B/A/EBA0A152-F426-47E6-9E3F-EFB686E3CA20/VS2010SP1dvd1.iso).

Comment: I believe, what is happening, VS is stuck on your project file. You need to right-click on project--unload, right-click-edit... Find reference to visual basic and remove it. Save, reload project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a fix, not sure if a workaround. I have installed VS2015 community ed. and everything seems to work fine now.

The issue affected ALL the projects and solutions on my box (it was not sln related), I have spent lot of hours trying to repair, replace references, reload projects... The only way to have it working again was to install a brand new version of VS. Thanks MS for the time lost :(